# pass state as props in component child in React

Tags: components, state, create-react-app, react-props

I get data from a local server, catch them with axios.get, and save them in my state. It's ok, but when i want to pass it as props in an component child, KABOOM! Doesn't work. 
I'm looking for a solution, I think it's lyfecycle problem but i'm not sure.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style/App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import Table from './Components/Table'


class App extends Component {

    state = {
      tabData: [],
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
      this.getDataFromServer()
    }

    getDataFromServer = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:8000")
      .then((response) => {
        const twentyObj = response.data.splice(-20);
        this.setState({
          tabData:twentyObj
        })
        console.log(this.state.tabData)
      })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }


  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Table stateData={this.state.tabData}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Developer Tools Browser say:
TypeError: _this.props is undefined
(for this.props.tabData.map in Table.js)

**Table.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Cell from './Cell'


const Table = (props) => {


    return(

        <div>
        {this.props.tabData.map( item => 
          <Cell key={item.index}
                time={item.timestamp}
                nasdaq={item.stocks.NASDAQ}
                cac40={item.stocks.CAC40}/>
        )}
      </div>
    )
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Table` is functional component `this` has no value there and thats what the error message is telling you.

You should use `props.tabData` and not `this.props.tabData`

UPDATE:

Here you are passing it as stateData and not tabData Try props.stateData